# Как подсчитать количество использований слова в строке?

Tags: c++

Допустим есть строкеа "Tom, Tom, and Tom went to the river.", нужно посчитать сколько раз в нём использовалось слово Tom. При этом нужно пользоваться С-шными функциями. Я попробовал разбить строку на слова функцией `strtok`, но она после каждого слова вставляет `'\0'` и получается не так как я задумал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну почему бы и не `strtok`? Например, так:

```
int counts(char * s, const char * m)
{
    const char * delimeters = " ,.\t:;\"\'"; // Все, что разделяет слова :)
    int cnt = 0;
    for(s = strtok(s,delimeters);s;s = strtok(0,delimeters))
        if (!strcmp(s,m)) ++cnt;
    return cnt;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char s[] = "Tom, Tom, and Tom went to the river.";

    printf("There are %d \"Tom\" in string\n",counts(s,"Tom"));

}
```

Программа - [здесь](https://ideone.com/OJ2Lhp).

Comment: Спасибо, мне помог ваш цикл, я там подшаманил и вставил функцию strstr, не знаю почему у меня вчера это не получалось...

Answer (score 2):

Вот реализация типичного алгоритма поиска количества вхождений подстроки в строку на Си. Не претендую на оптимальность, но она рабочая.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t substrCount(char * str, char * substr)
{
    size_t counter = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        str = strstr(str, substr);  // Возвращает указатель на первое вхождение подстроки в строку
                                    // либо NULL, если вхождений нет
        if (!str)
            break;
        ++counter;
        str += strlen(substr);      // Идём дальше по строке (откидываем то, что уже найдено)
    }

    return counter;
}

int main() 
{
    char * x = "Tom, Tom, and Tom went to the river.";  // Здесь исходная строка

    printf("%d\n", substrCount(x, "Tom"));  // Сюда в кавычки искомую строку


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

В центре событий тут функция `strstr`, которая принимает указатели на исходную строку и на подстроку и возвращает указатель на первое вхождение подстроки в строку. То есть выполняет поиск подстроки. Всё, что нам остаётся сделать – зациклить этот поиск, на каждой итерации продвигаясь дальше по строке, чтобы поиск каждый раз производился в той части строки, где мы ещё не искали. Это достигается наращиванием указателя строки на размер подстроки (== сдвигом по строке на кол-во символов, равное размеру подстроки).

Comment: ```while (str = strstr(str, substr))
    {
        ++counter;
        str += strlen(substr);
    }```

Comment: Полохо, так как сработает и на Tomcat, и на Tomato...